# ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] Operation (“add”) failed-address: ([(“subsystem” => "metrics")]): java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, keycloak, mysql-connector

I am trying to deploy Keycloak in my local pc with mysql

However, when I try to run standalone.sh It gives me following error :

[image: It gives me NullPointerException]

Here is the database configurations I did

```
  <spi name="connectionsJpa">
            <provider name="default" enabled="true">
                <properties>
                    <property name="dataSource" value="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"/>
                   <!-- <property name="initializeEmpty" value="true"/> -->
                   <!-- <property name="migrationStrategy" value="update"/> -->
                    <property name="initializeEmpty" value="false"/>
                    <property name="migrationStrategy" value="manual"/>
                   <property name="migrationExport" value="${jboss.home.dir}/keycloak- 
                database-update.sql"/>
                </properties>
            </provider>
        </spi>
```

Keycloak Datasource changes :-

```
 <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" 
          enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics- 
       enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics- 
       enabled:false}}">
                <connection- 
      url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
             <!--- <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool- 
       name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics- 
      enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                <connection- 
         url>jdbc:h2:${jboss.server.data.dir}/keycloak;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>  -->
            <!-- mysql -->
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" 
              enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics- 
              enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics- 
              enabled:false}}">
              <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloakdata? 
               useSSL=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
              <driver>mysql</driver>
              <pool>
                  <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                  <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
              </pool>
              <security>
                  <user-name>user</user-name>
                  <password>user</password>
              </security>
              <validation>
                  <valid-connection-checker class- 
             name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                  <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                  <exception-sorter class- 
             name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
              </validation>
          </datasource>
```

Declare and Load JDBC Driver

```
           <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                  <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
              <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
          </driver> 
            </drivers>
```

I also added module and its dependency to jboss (jboss-cli.sh)

```
module add --name=com.mysql --resources=/keycloak- 
13.0.1/modules/system/layers/keycloak/com/mysql/main/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar -- 
dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

increase keyclaok server’s timeout

```
        <local-cache name="actionTokens">
                <heap-memory size="-1"/>
                <expiration max-idle="-1" interval="900000"/>
              </local-cache>

        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="20000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled- 
       cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="20000"/>
        </session-bean>


        <pools>
            <bean-instance-pools>
                <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-cpu-count" 
                instance-acquisition-timeout="20" instance-acquisition-timeout- 
                unit="MINUTES"/>
                <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-worker-pools" 
               instance-acquisition-timeout="20" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
            </bean-instance-pools>
        </pools>
```

I refered the following articles when trying this
[Connect mysql server to keycloak](https://dev.to/donadams50/connect-mysql-server-to-keycloak-3d6e) , [Setting up Keycloak Standalone with MySQL Database](https://medium.com/@pratik.dandavate/setting-up-keycloak-standalone-with-mysql-database-7ebb614cc229) and [Relational Database Setup in Server Installation and Configuration Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_installation/#_database)

Full stack trace as below :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Adding the full stack trace would be helpful. Can you just paste the stack trace itself here?

Comment: Hi! I added it in to the question,

Comment: I'm not sure what that could be. Do you use metrics? If not you could probably just remove the subsystem.

Comment: this kind of errors leads to fault aim. always search the error in above logs. any fatal or error might caused it. it seems your database is't update look at https://capture.dropbox.com/LDtXFKw7vmj54IA2